# phpunitDbTest.php: command not found

Tags: php, phpunit, mamp

I have just installed **PHPUNIT** and I am trying to run this to test:

```
imac001:unit administrator$ phpunit/DbTest.php
```

But my result is always:

> -bash: phpunitDbTest.php: command not found

Can someone give me a hand on this? I am working on **Yii** application and I am running it on **MAMP**.

Comment: Are you sure you're not putting the slash the other way (e.g. `phpunit\DbTest.php`)?  If you use a backslash on the command line, it'll generally escape text and treat the next character as a literal, which is how you could end up with `phpunitDbTest.php`.  Alternatively, you might try something like: `php <pathTo>/DbTest.php`

Answer (score 0):

If "phpunit/DbTest.php" is path to test, command should looks like this

```
phpunit phpunit/DbTest.php
```